# how can i call function inside another function.?

Tags: python

In Python, it is possible to pass a function as a argument to another function. Write a function useFunction(func, num) that takes in a function and a number as arguments. The useFunction should produce the output shown in the examples given below.

Examples

```
>>> def addOne(x):
        return x + 1
>>> useFunction(addOne, 4)
25
>>> useFunction(addOne, 9)
100
>>> useFunction(addOne, 0)
1
```

i am stuck in this challenge.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Why don't you just try that?

Comment: This is clearly homework; you'll never learn anything if you just ask for the answers on SO.

Comment: In other words, what have you tried yourself so far, *how did you get stuck?*

Comment: The same way you would call one outside a function

Comment: def addOne(x):
        return x + 1
        
def useFunction(addOne, num): 
        pass

Comment: That's not an attempt at anything.

Comment: i know but can you give me the example , just idea.

Comment: Do you see what `useFunction()` does with the value returned by  `addOne()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can do something like this:

```
def addOne(x):
    return x+1

def useFunction(addOne, x):
    return addOne(x)**2
```

Now whenever you call `useFunction(addOne, x)` you'll get the desired output.

```
>>> useFunction(addOne, 4)
25
>>> useFunction(addOne, 9)
100
>>> useFunction(addOne, 8)
81
>>> useFunction(addOne, 6)
49
>>>
```